# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message (Canva)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I been trying to get this canva to work for like an hour but it keeps throwing this error

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

My code

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  const { Welcomer } = require("canvacord");

  const card = new Welcomer()
  .setUsername(member.user.username)
  .setDiscriminator(member.user.discriminator)
  .setMemberCount(member.guild.memberCount.toLocaleString())
  .setGuildName(member.guild.name)
  .setAvatar(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png" }))
  .setColor("border", "#eb26dd")
  .setColor("username-box", "#eb26dd")
  .setColor("discriminator-box", "#eb26dd")
  .setColor("message-box", "#eb26dd")
  .setColor("title", "#eb26dd")
  .setColor("avatar", "#eb26dd")
  .setText("member-count", "- {count} members")
  .setText("title", "welcome")
  .setText("message", "welcome to MD")


  card.build()
      .then(buffer => client.channels.cache.get("942901196119760896").send(new MessageAttachment(buffer, "welcome.png")));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending attachments in `discord.js` v13, you need to specify that you are sending a [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment) by using the `file` property when sending the attachment. It might look like this:

```js
card.build()
        .then(buffer => {
            const attachment = new MessageAttachment(buffer, 'welcome.png');
            client.channels.cache.get("channel-id").send({ files: [attachment]})
        });
```